# how do you use and change innerHTML in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, innerhtml

I recently started using react, and most of it works wonders, but i really cannot understand hhow youre supposed to change html dynamically

Heres some example code i tried to create:

```
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.';
var speed = 50;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
```

It seems next to impossible to do in react, which is weird since i got the impression that these kinds of things should be easier in reacy.
You can run the code [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_typewriter)

Comment: You should render the HTML from the state, and then upon updating the state it automatically re-renders.

Comment: what do you need inner html when using react ? you can trigger and use everything that comes into your mind when you want to render it using components.

Comment: I wrote an example for you to better understand ReactJS: https://jsfiddle.net/9uzqLkax/

Comment: The idea of React is to let it handle DOM mutations, not doing them yourself. The whole idea behind it was that DOM mutations make the browser run slow, thus it's better that you handle the computing part and let the framework handle DOM mutations on its own.
There is nevertheless a `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` property that you can use for writing innerHtml, but as you can tell by its name it's not recommended

Answer (score 3):

In React you just modify `state` and DOM is updated automatically. Your example could look something like below. There is no need to update html directly.

You can also check [this introductory tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) which shows main React concepts.

```js
class ReactTypeWriter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.state = { text: ""};
    }

    handleClick() {
        var i = 0;
        var txt = 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.';
        var speed = 50;
        let typeWriter = () => {
            if (i < txt.length) {
                this.setState({ text: txt.substring(0, i++) });
                setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
            }
        };
        typeWriter();
    }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Typewriter</h1>
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me</button>
          <p id="demo">{this.state.text}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ReactTypeWriter />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```